# Switching and current reading circuit simulation

Tags: analog, simulation, current-measurement, switching

I have plan to design a circuit for controlling 200 W heater with 28 V.

For my circuit I planned use IRF530 for switching heater. First question is that ok?

Second question is I also need to read current drawn by heater, so which is true using Rsense and opamp or using for example a Maxim current sense amplifier?

Last question is what must be R1 R2 and Rsense values, and how can I simulate in Circuitlab (or any online program)?

Comment: Welcome! _"And how can I simulate this switching and current reading circuit, selecting required resistor R1 R2 and Rsense to achieve my goal?"_ Any SPICE program can do this. There are several to choose from. Have you tried Falstad or LTspice?

Comment: @winny ltspice seems online and no i havent tested infact first i need to finalize design.

Comment: LTspice is a desktop program. Simulations is a very normal part of electronic design. I don't finalize any design without both simulations and in-circuit tests. But this is a very simple circuit so it's of course possible to hand calculate all values.

Comment: Do you need to control the "power" or the "temperature" of the heater?

Comment: @Antonio51 No, I dont need to control any of them, but also i dont want to lose my mosfet because of overheat if component is wrong good to know that.

Comment: If power supply is "28V" and heater is "200W", why do you need "measure" the current?

Comment: @Antonio51 to monitor current for battery calculation.

Comment: If FPGA output is analog, then ok.

Comment: Why? U is fixed. R is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is going to be a long post. So have your sausage, black pudding, baked beans, and cheesy crumpet.

---

> For my circuit I planned use IRF530 for switching Heater. First question is that ok?

Your heater draws 200W / 28V = 7.15A. I don't know what type of heater it is, but maybe the initial turn-on current can be high for a short time. Anyway, for MOSFET, there are few things you need to consider:

- **Max current:** Make sure the continuous drain current rating higher than 7.15A.
- **Losses & On Resistance:** Make sure the on resistance of the MOSFET is low enough to keep the losses and therefore thermals manageable.
- **Gate Driving:** One thing about the MOSFETs is that the minimum on resistance (and therefore minimum losses) can be achieved with high enough gate drive voltage. Make sure the output of your FPGA is high enough to turn the MOSFET on **fully**.

Now let's have a look at your IRF530:

- Max continuous current is 10A (for high case temperature) which is higher than 7.15A but also close enough to worry about. It's always good to leave a safety margin.
- On resistance, which is shown as R<sub>DS-on</sub> in the datasheets, is 0.16 Ohms. This means the MOSFET will dissipate \$P_D=0.16\Omega \cdot 7.15 A^2=8.2W\$. This level of loss is really high for your application, therefore requires serious heatsinking.
- The gate threshold voltage can be as high as 4V. I don't know if your FPGA is able to generate 10V (because this is the voltage where the MOSFETs' on resistance is rated at) or higher output voltage for maximum driving.

**CONCLUSION:** You might want to pick another MOSFET with

- Higher continuous drain current rating (20A or higher)
- Lower on resistance (Up to 5 mΩ should be alright for your application but the prices can be eye-watering)
- Logic-level gate rating (consider your FPGA's logic output levels so the max gate threshold voltage, V<sub>GS-th</sub>, shouldn't reach that voltage. Generally, for 3.3V systems, having max gate threshold voltage of 2V or lower is alright.)

---

> using Rsense and Opamp or using for example a Maxim current sense amplifier?

A current sense amplifier has also an op amp internally. Some have even the shunt resistor. So it shouldn't matter which way you go for. But the answer depends on size, cost and accuracy requirements. You want the smallest possible size? What's your budget for this application? What accuracy you require for your current measurement (e.g. 1 milliamp accuracy, 100 milliamp accuracy)? Answer these questions and select the approach accordingly.

- Current sense amplifiers can be either fixed gain or adjustable gain. Adjustable gain ones require one or two external resistors. Op amps need resistors and capacitors.
- Current sense amplifiers can have low offset error (which can be crucial for the accuracy) but there are op amps having really low offset errors as well. What offset error you can compensate depends on the sense resistor.

Note that the sense resistor should be low enough to make the losses and thermals manageable, and high enough to beat the amplifier's offset error for maximum accuracy. For example, if you pick a 0.5 milliohm shunt resistor then the drop across it will be around 3mV. If you pick an op amp or sense amplifier having a max offset error of 3mV then you'll have a problem. So you'll need to pick an amplifier or op amp with really low offset error, but those are generally expensive. If you pick a 1 Ohm shunt resistor then you won't have any offset-error-related problems but the losses will be 50 W. So pick a sensible value.

For your application, up to 25 milliohms should be alright. The drop across it will be around 0.18 Volts which allows you to pick any amplifier regardless of its offset error (still keep the accuracy in mind), and the total losses will be around 1.3 Watts so a 2W or 3W SMD resistor can be used.

---

> Last question is what must be R1 R2 and Rsense values, and how can I simulate in Circuitlab (or any online program)?

I answered the question about sense resistor above. So I'm skipping this.

R1 is to keep the gate shunted to ground to prevent gate floating which can cause false turn on of MOSFET. Anything between 1k to 100k is alright.

R2 has two purposes:

- **Limiting gate drive current:** This is basically to protect the driver (FPGA in your case). The gate-source capacitor of the MOSFET will be empty when the MOSFET is off. So when you try to turn it on, since that cap is technically short when empty, a really high current can flow trough the driver. Depending on the current limits of your FPGA you need to limit that current by placing a resistor according to Ohm's law. For example, if the peak current of your FPGA output is 50mA, and if the drive voltage is 3.3V, then R1 should be **at least** 3.3V / 50m = **68R**.
- **Turn on time:** You can protect the driver by increasing the series resistance (known as gate stopper resistor) but that brings a problem: The higher the resistance the slower the turn on. If the MOSFET turns on slow enough then the initial losses will be higher. If you drive the MOSFET frequently (which doesn't seem to be part of your application but anyway) then the losses will be high.

With simulation tools (ISIS/Proteus, LTSpice - my favourite, etc.) you can see the behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable feedback really impressive Mr Kilic. I understood that my selections is not appropriate so pls update the answer as advising a Mosfet and a Current sense amplifier, accuracy and budget is not important for now. And one last thing pls attach a simulation circuit link to follow behavior of circuit in your favorite sim tool as i have no experience in that too. Regards.

Comment: @deaerM Unfortunately this is not a place to suggest or recommend a specific product as it's off-topic. I tried my best to give as many details as possible for you to select an appropriate component. You can go to Digikey or Mouser website and use the parametric search. Take the availability into account as some components might be out of stock. And for simulation, I'm not able to prepare a simulation file for you at the moment but you can have a look at your favourite simulation tools or you can try LTSpice - its tutorials are really good and well-detailed.

Comment: I saw some other posts that people sometimes control MOSFET using FPGA but through an "optocoupler" (guess prevent FPGA to damage). So as we directly connected through R2, i wanted to ask should we use optocoupler or not?

Comment: @deaerM there are a few ways to drive a MOSFET and the isolated method (using optocouplers or gate drive transformers) is one of them. Isolated driving becomes beneficial or even necessary when the system is noise-sensitive or the target/load is completely isolated. In your case, check the peak output current capability of your FPGA's output ports and if they're too low (e.g. less than 10 mA) then you can consider using an optocoupler as it'll decrease the necessary output current. Otherwise, I don't see a necessity or a benefit of isolated driving.